# How to merge two databases in MySql

Tags: mysql, database, merge, schema, phpmyadmin

I need to merge two MySql databases.

- DBtwo is a copy of DBone.
- I added data to a table_x in DBone, and I added datas to a table_y in DBtwo.
- I need to keep data added in DBOne, while merging all other edits –such as deleted entries- made in DBTwo.
- Schemas, then, are identical, while each DB have different data from different tables.

Thank you all for your help.

Edit:
I was forgetting. I added columns to table_x that are foreign keys to table_y. So DBone has some entries that have been inserted without columns I added to table_x in DBtwo. :/

Comment: Hi check this link http://www.everymanhosting.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=42

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, I too, before posting my question, did a Google search for it. The problem, here, is that the tutorial explains how to merge two **tables**, not two **databases**. Also, it talks about two completely equal schemas, while in my case I altered and added some columns here and there in different tables.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a copy of the original database before the merge? If not, what you are asking is impossible. Here is the problem:

The original database has these records:

```
{a, b, c}
```

In table_x, you add a d, so now you have:

```
{a, b, c, d}
```

In table y, you remove a b, so you have:

```
{a, c}
```

You now attempt to merge these two data sets:

```
{a, b, c, d}
{a, c}
```

Without reference to the original, how do you know whether b and d should be in the new set. If they weren't in the original and you added them since the fork, they should be included. If they were in the original and you deleted them in table_y since the merge, they should not be included.

Assuming you do have access, you'll want to do something like:

```
insert into table_y
select *
from table_x x
where x.id not in (select id from table_x_original)
```

And then rename table_y to table_x (if you want table_x to be the new data source). If your ids are generated and you may have conflicts, you'll want to replace the * with a list of all the columns other than the id column to generate a new sequential id.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trigger.  Please see the MySQL documentation for your implementation regarding, triggers, functions and procedures.

Comment: Interesting feature ([MySql trigger functions reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)) but how could I use them in my case?

Comment: As you update DBOne.table_x a trigger can likely replicate the changes to DBTwo.table_y.